# ApiResponse class with an Id as a Json key

Tags: java, json, spring, api, class

I am trying to consume data from some public API but I am stuck on some issue about the design of this data. I am using Spring.

I am doing it with the classic way :

```
private ResponseEntity<ApiResponse> getVehicules() {
    final String methodUri = "/vehicules";
    RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();

    HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers.setAccept(Arrays.asList(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON));
    HttpEntity<String> entity = new HttpEntity<String>("parameters", headers);

    return restTemplate.exchange(apiUri + methodUri, HttpMethod.GET, entity, ApiResponse.class);
}
```

The problem is more about the design of ApiResponse class. Indeed, the api returned json looks like :

```
{
    "status": "ok",
    "meta": {
        "count": 2,
        "page_total": 1,
        "limit": 100,
        "page": null
    },
    "data": {
        "18497": {
            "id": 18497,
            "name": "vehiculeName",
            "nation": "vehiculeNation"
        },
        "52467": {
            "id": 52467,
            "name": "anotherVehiculeName",
            "nation": "anotherVehiculeNation"
        }
    }
}
```

So how do I manage the id (The one before the brackets - ex `18497:{...}` ) in my class ?

I am stuck trying to create a Data class because of that and as you can imagine, its a public API not mine, so I can't change anything on this side.

Comment: data would be a Map<Integer, IdNameAndNation>. Nite that this is nt valid JSON. Keys in objects must be strings, inside double quotes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This kind of weird Json (using dynamic information in field names) is tricky to figure out how to read. But the solution is simple.

You will need to use a `Map` on your `ApiResponse` class, like:

```
class ApiResponse {

    // other fields

    @JsonProperty("data")
    private Map<String, VehicleResponse> vehicles;

}
```

The `VehicleResponse` is a normal class with `id`, `name`, `nation` fields.

As result, the map `vehicles` will have as `key` the `18497` (and etc) and as `value` the information about the vehicle (id, name, nation) in `VehicleResponse`.

Comment: You don't need any specific deserializer. Jackson knows how to deserialize the JSON, since the type is in the generic type of the field.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest and fastest way to build java classes from JSON is by using a schema mapper like this one:

http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/

It generates java classes directly from JSON and also allows you to specify many different options such as the annotation types that should be generated.